# How to reset username to default?

Tags: support

How do I remove my custom username and let it go back to the default of: `user123456` or whatever it was?

Comment: Can't you just make up a number and then change it yourself?

Comment: You can't, as there really isn't a practical reason to do so, unless you wrote down the username.  Just enter random numbers or whatever.  Here's one option for you, courtesy of http://www.random.org/: `user95719763`.  Also, note that a previous name will probably still be available just by searching for a cached version of the page.

Comment: Isn't it your userid? In OP's case user2199852.

Comment: @Sumurai8 it's the user id of the oldest site you joined, which does indeed happen to be SO in this case: http://stackexchange.com/users/2531675/user?tab=accounts

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system doesn't have a default option, but it's pretty trivial to do so yourself. The number after `user` is your userID (assuming that's the first site you signed up for).

So in my case,

[image: My profile]]

`user871050`